# Do we need a JOIN for this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have two 2 tables:

```
tbl_projekte [uid,werbemittel,projekt_name,kunden_id]

tbl_kunden [uid, kunden_name]
```

We are using this statement to select recordsets from tbl_projekte:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_projekte WHERE werbemittel ='12' ORDER BY kunden_id ASC
```

How do we get the SQL statement to ORDER BY kunden_name?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Seeing as `kunden_name` in the `tbl_kunden` table and not the `tbl_projekte` table, yes you need to `JOIN`.

Comment: Posting german column names here, is pretty confusing for the users from all over the world. Also you should avoid that in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a join for this

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM tbl_projekte p
INNER JOIN tbl_kunden k on k.uid = p.kunden_id
WHERE p.werbemittel ='12' 
ORDER BY k.kunden_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to order by customer name, then do it this way:

```
SELECT p.uid, p.werbemittel, p.projekt_name 
FROM tbl_projekte p
LEFT JOIN tbl_kunden k ON k.uid = p.kunden_id
WHERE werbemittel ='12' 
ORDER BY k.kunden_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The ',' is an implicit natural join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_projekte, tbl_kunden  
WHERE werbemittel ='12' 
ORDER BY kunden_name ASC
```

If you want to be explicit:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_projekte NATURAL JOIN tbl_kunden  
WHERE werbemittel ='12' 
ORDER BY kunden_name ASC
```

A 'natural join' merge the tables that have the same value for the primary key (uid in your case).